# Ever seen a ringed group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

A locally ringed space is a common generalization of schemes and various manifolds. I am wondering about a locally ringed group which should be a common generalization of group schemes and various Lie groups.

Questions: did anyone ever work it out?  are there any references?

Comment: when I try to reinvent it my wings take dream very soon: the multiplication is defined $G\times G \rightarrow G$ but $G\times G$ should not be a product of topological spaces, it is not for the schemes...

Comment: What about something purely formal such as "group object in the category of locally ring space"?

Comment: Tommaso: presumably that wascally wabbit would object that with your definition groups schemes would not be ringed groups (see the last paragraph of his question).

Comment: I will be more careful when making comments. Sorry.

Comment: This leads me to the (probably irrelevant) question: Does one ever talk about the category of "locally ringed sites"? And if so, does one do it without using stalks? I'm thinking of topological-in-the-sense-of-Grothendieck groups.

Comment: @ Tommaso. You won't even get all Lie groups with this attitude. Say, consider an analytic Lie group. In $G\times G$, the local ring is something like $C[[X_i,Y_i]]$ which is not $C[[X_i]]\otimes C[[Y_i]]$ you suggest but its completion.

Comment: I don't think that there is a common generalization. LRS (locally ringed spaces) and Mfd (manifolds) have all products, but the inclusion Mfd -> LRS does not preserve products.

Comment: Dear Tom: Locally ringed topoi seems to be the concept you are getting at.  The concept makes sense even without stalks (though the definition is not obvious at first glance) and it is sometimes convenient. 

Comment: @ Martin B. Exacatactly!! All it means one has to work hard and include topology and locally ringness on $G\times G$ into the structure of a ringed group, similarly to topology of $G$ being part of the structure of topological group...

Comment: And off course it is not that easy (imho) as a group scheme is not a group... Bother...